# How to get to black market on bo3 multiplayer

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-3

Please me and my brother are trying to get classified guns but it takes the black market

Answer (score 2):

You need to play matches and earn crypto keys.  Exchange the crypto keys for black market cases and you have a chance to get a classified weapon.

The alternative is to purchase CoD points and exchange those for rare black market cases.